# The webpart is duplicated in case of the SharePoint app updating

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint hosted app.
There is a list in that app, and it is brought through web part on the page.

```
       <div>

                <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="WebPartZone" >
                    <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart
                        runat="server"
                        ListUrl="Lists/IdeasList">
                    </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
                </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>

            </div>
```

Everything works well but there is one problem, in case of application updating the page on which is placed a web part is replaced normally (html a code), but the web part is duplicated (on the page one more copy of web part is added below).

How to add web part on the page that it wasn't duplicated in case of updating?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and what I did is to remove the webparts before update.
You can delete them manually via URL.
Another option is to implement an event receiver which will delete the webparts before.
Hope this helps you.